# See any risks / potential crashes in this code? Would like to improve it

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

After releasing my app and putting Crashlytics in, I noticed i'm getting a few crashes each day in a particular area of code. I wanted to see if the community could help me discern it, as the data gathered isn't helpful enough to identify what's going on.

I wasn't able to see this during my testing and with the 25 beta testers, but now that I have several thousand users it's a problem each day.

Basically the idea is to send a request out to grab some content (as a JSON array) and then pull it into the phone.

I went a bit more generic in approach, so hopefully I made a few mistakes that others can find? Thanks so much!

This makes a request out, gets an array, and then saves. I see where I could put a try/catch, but other than that not sure why it could crash. Maybe the server i'm on occasionally times out or something else happens?
Crashlytics seems to suggest it's on this line:

```
NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)
```

> 0x00000001001117c4
>   _TFZFC118MyProxy8GetAsyncFMS0_U_S_14Deserializable__FTGCS_10RequestQ__8callbackFGCS_11ResponseGSaQ0___T__T_U_FTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError__T_
>   (MyProxy.swift:141)

Ok here are the proxy functions:

```
class func GetAsync<R, T: Deserializable>(request: Request<R>, callback: (Response<Array<T>>) -> ())
{
    var list = Array<T>()
    var response = Response<Array<T>>()
    let serverRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: API_URL + request.Url)!)
    serverRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(serverRequest,
        completionHandler: {
            data, r, error in

            if error != nil {
                response.Status = .ERROR
            } else {

                 let responseArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                //Append each item from the array to a list
                for item: AnyObject in responseArray {
                    let row = T(dict: item as! NSDictionary)
                    list.append(row)
                }

                    response = Response<Array<T>>(status: ResponseCode.OK, value: list)
                }

            }

            callback(response)
    })


    task.resume()
}
```

And for the cases where I retrieve a single JSON item from my server, I wrote a similar one (the callback is for a single object, not an array:

```
class func GetAsync<R, T: Deserializable>(request: Request<R>, callback: (Response<T>) -> ())
    {
        var response = Response<T>()
        let serverRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: API_URL + request.Url)!)
        serverRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(serverRequest,
            completionHandler: {
                data, r, error in

                if error != nil {
                    response.Status = .ERROR
                } else {

                    var responseStatus: ResponseCode = .NO_CODE
                    let responseObject: AnyObject?
                    do {
                        responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)
                    } catch _ {
                        responseObject = nil
                    }

                    if (responseObject != nil) {
                        let responseDictionary = responseObject as! NSDictionary
                        let code = responseDictionary["code"] as! String?

                        if (code != nil) {
                            let c = ResponseCode(rawValue: code!)
                            if (c != nil) {
                                responseStatus = c!
                            }
                        }

                        response = Response<T>(status: responseStatus, value: T(dict: responseDictionary))
                    }
                }

            callback(response)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

See any bad coding practices or areas I can improve on? Thank you!

Comment: I would put this kind of question to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least this line:

```
let responseArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
```

should be changed to something like:

```
do {
    if let data = data, let responseArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSArray {
        // use responseArray here
    } else {
        // the data was nil or the JSON wasn't an array
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

to avoid crashing with nil data or bad JSON.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful for my  next version.